# Dynamics 365 and Box integration

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, box, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-365

We are integrating Dynamics 365 Online and Box to use Box as a content layer for CRM opportunity documents. The trust settings in Dynamics 365 does not allow API calls to Box. The setting needed for that is medium. How do I change trust settings in Dynamics 365 or is it even allowed?

Comment: It isn't. You are supposed to use Sharepoint/Onedrive For Business

Answer (score 0):

You can use Box, but with the help of 3rd-parties like Zapier, Workato, Skyvia, etc. Here you can find more about this kind of integration:  https://community.box.com/t5/Business-Apps-Forums/How-to-Integrate-Box-with-MS-Dynamics-365/td-p/34829

Answer (score -1):

To change the trust settings in Dynamics 365 Online, you can follow these steps:

1. Go to the Dynamics 365 admin center and sign in with administrative credentials.
2. Select the instance for which you want to change the trust settings.
3. In the left navigation pane, select Settings, and then select Administration.
4. In the Trust section, select Security.
5. Choose the appropriate trust level for your integration with Box (in this case, you would select Medium).
6. Save your changes.

Note that changing the trust settings in Dynamics 365 Online can have security implications, so you should only make changes if you understand the risks and have a specific need for it. Also, make sure to test your integration thoroughly after changing the trust settings to ensure that everything is working correctly.

If you are not authorized to make these changes, you should contact your Dynamics 365 Online administrator or IT department for assistance.